# Shader - Color blending

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I would like to know how to blend colors in a specific way.

Let's imagine that I have a color **(A)** and an other color **(B)**.

I would like to blend them in such a way that if I choose white for the **(B)** then the output color is **(A)** but if have any other color for **(B)** it outputs a blending of **(A)** and **(B)**.

- I've tried the addition, but it doesn't give the expected result.
- I've tried the multiplicative blending it's quite good for the **(B)** white value but it fail for a blue **(B)** and red **(A)** colors.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Your case sounds like you shouldn't try to compute your result, but to use branching in your shader. Maybe you need to add some more specific information (code, explicit use-case), otherwise I would suggest a simple `if` :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to avoid branching. And an if statement would not give the appropriate result as I would like to get a blending effect but I don't find a good way to do that even with lerp... The color (A) should appear only when going to white for color (B).

Comment: When you say you want "a blending of A and B", how do you want them to be blended? What determines how much of A and how much of B should be used?

Comment: It's hard to explain a special problem on an abstract basis. If you reveal your real use case it would be far more easier to understand what exactly you want to achieve. And would make it easier for the SO community to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

With GLSL, the simplest approach is probably to use a branch. If `colA` and `colB` are the two vectors (of type `vec4`) holding your colors **A** and **B**:

```
if (any(lessThan(colB.xyz, vec3(1.0)))) {
    outColor = colB;
} else {
    outColor = colA;
}
```

Or, if you really want to avoid a branch, you could rely more on built-in functions. For example, using the observation that if all components are in the range [0.0, 1.0], the dot product of the vector with itself is 3.0 for the vector (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), and smaller for all other vectors:

```
outColor = mix(colB, colA, step(3.0, dot(colB.xyz, colB.xyz)))
```

You will have to benchmark to find out which of these is faster.

There may be some concern about floating point precision in the comparisons for both variations above. I believe it should be fine, since 1.0 can be represented as a float exactly. But if you do run into problems, you may want to allow for some imprecision by changing the constants that `colB` is compared against to slightly smaller values.

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to achieve but it's like having an if statement as it "jumps" to the A color when having B = (1, 1, 1).
I would like to know if it's possible to avoid this "jump" and blend smoothly.

Comment: Oh, that's not what the original version of your question specified. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Right, I apologize and I corrected the question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid branching in a `shader`, one technique is to use lerp (`linear interpolation`). That is, use the would-be conditional variable as the lerp factor, so if it's `0` it's `one` color and if it's `1` it's the `other` color.

Be sure to reverse the logic since the second argument is what it blends to if `cond=1`. This also allows you to blend half way.

Example:

Instead of

```
Color result = (cond)? A:B;
```

use:

```
Color result=lerp(cond,B,A);
```